# Erro com syntax - retorno de URL

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal

estou com um novo problema, estou a algumas horas tentando identificar o erro da syntax abaixo:

Código:

```
<?php

session_start();

@$usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
@$senha = $_SESSION["senha"];

if(isset($usuario) && isset($senha)){

    header("Location: cp_admin.php");
}

?>

<body>
    <main>
        <div id="login">

            <?php 

            if(isset($_GET["url"])){

                $url = $_GET["url"];

            }

            ?>

            <form action="acoes/user-login.php?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" method="POST"> 

            <?php } else { ?>
                <form action="acoes/user-login.php" method="POST"> 
            <?php } ?>    

                Usúario <input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" placeholder="USÚARIO" /> 
                Senha <input type="password" name="user-pass" id="user-pass" placeholder="SENHA" />
                <input type="submit" name="user-login" id="user-login" value="Entrar" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="content-logo-2"><img src="../img/android-icon-36x36.png"></div>
        <div id="content-logo"> <!--<img src="../img/logo_180.png"> --></div>
    </main>
```

O problema é que quando tento acessar á pagina para verificar se o código esta funcionando (Eu sei que não está), ele me retorno o seguinte erro:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\Portal_Noticias\painel\index.php on line 74"

a linha 74 tem os seguintes códigos:

Gostaria de saber qual o erro que estou cometendo

Fico no aguardo

Comment: As linhas que estão com problemas são estas:

<?php } else { ?> <form action="acoes/user-login.php" method="POST"> <?php } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o código:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["url"])){
    $url = $_GET["url"];
}
?>
```

Tente remover o ultimo colchetes `}`, é aonde se encontra o erro :)

Comment: Cara uma parada tão simples, as vezes é bom parar e fazer outro dia:

Ficou assim:
            <?php} else 
            <form action="acoes/user-login.php" method="POST"> 
           ?>

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @CíceroAlves Caso tenha ajudado e solucionado seu problema marque minha resposta como correta, obrigado.